# Why can't remove vim?

Tags: debian, vim, uninstall

```
uname  -a
Linux MiWiFi-R3-srv 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2~bpo9+1 (2020-05-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo dpkg -l vim
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                  Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-=====================================-=======================-=======================-===============================================================================
un  vim                                   <none>                  <none>                  (no description available)
```

Try to remove it:

```
sudo apt remove vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'vim' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

When to type `vim` in console:

[image]

```
sudo  dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which vim))
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/vim
ls -l /usr/local/bin/vim
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root staff 2946336 Jul 17 20:34 /usr/local/bin/vim
```

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg -S $(readlink -f $(which vim))`? Also, what operating system are you using? I am assuming it is some sort of Debian-based Linux since you mention `dpkg`, but please [edit] your question and tell us exactly what your OS is.

Comment: Linux MiWiFi-R3-srv 4.19.0-0.bpo.9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2~bpo9+1 (2020-05-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does your `readlink` support the `-f` flag? Is `/usr/local/bin/vim` a symlink? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/vim`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are either one of two things:

The package that is installed isn't `vim` and is actually `vim-tiny`, `vim-athena`, `vim-gtk`, `vim-gtk3`, or something else. To find out if this is the case, use the following command:

```
dpkg-query -l | grep vim
```

It could also be that the `vim` on your system has been compiled from source and wouldn't be found by `apt` or `dpkg`. You can verify this with:

```
whereis vim
```

That will show any `vim` binaries located anywhere on the system including any not located in `/usr/bin` that may have been compiled in different locations such as `/opt` or `/usr/local`.

You can also just use a wildcard:

If you are using `apt` 1.9 or newer:

```
apt remove '~nvim.*'
```

If you are using `apt` 1.8 or older:

```
apt remove vim*
```

Answer (score 1):

Odds are the package name is not vim. It could be vim-tiny, vim-gnome, or god knows what.

To find it out, following [search for only installed packages using apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/305735), issue

```
apt list --installed vim*
```

Uninstall the vim packages listed there. For example, I get a line

```
vim-gtk3/stable,now 2:8.1.0875-5 amd64  [installiert]
```

So I would uninstall it with

```
apt remove vim-gtk3
```

Another simple way to find it out is to use tab-completion, if availabe. If you simply type

```
apt remove vim
```

and press tab twice, you would get a list of the packages installed that begin with `vim` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
dpkg-query -l | grep vim
ii  vim-common                                2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3                 all          Vi IMproved - Common files
ii  vim-gtk                                   2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3                 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - with GTK2 GUI
ii  vim-gui-common                            2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3                 all          Vi IMproved - Common GUI files
ii  vim-runtime                               2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3                 all          Vi IMproved - Runtime files
ii  vim-tiny                                  2:8.0.0197-4+deb9u3                 amd64        Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor - compact version
```

It is time to remove :

```
sudo apt remove  vim-common
```